# JQuery .on() - Cloning Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, ajax, clone, bind

I am working on a project where a user is able to perform some live search functions.  When the results of the live search are displayed, via JQuery Ajax, I need the user to have the ability to click on one of the displayed results and create a clone of that elsewhere on the page.  The problem I am finding is since these new live search results aren't processed on the first page load, I consider them to be 'phantom code' that doesn't exist to the DOM.  I have done some research on JQuery's on() as well as bind() functions but not sure how I can implement them into my own context.

Here is my JQuery

```
$(".add").click(function() {
        $(this).parent("li").clone(true).appendTo(".doc_list:first");                       

});
```

In that snippet (this) refers to my button which exists inside of the LI element (parent) which is dynamically created via the live search results. I need to copy that LI element.

If more code is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `.add` button added to DOM after page load ie. dynamically, so you need a delegate event handler (aka live).

```
$(".doc_list").on('click', '.add', function() {
    $(this).parent("li").clone(true).appendTo(".doc_list:first");
});
```

Here I user `.doc_list` as container, but if `.doc_list` also a dynamic element then replace it with some other static element that belong to DOM at page load.

Comment: Ideally you want to replace `"body"` with a selector for the nearest parent which is not dynamically loaded.

Comment: That, sir, did the trick.  Using it in this context makes it easier for me to understand how and what it achieves.  Thank you, very much!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to be holding up in Firefox.

Comment: I don't think I can do a sample in jsFiddle since he dynamic stuff is generated via an ASP page.

Comment: @Yuschick hi mate, you should check again carefully, I think above code should work, instead of `.doc_list` try with `body`, if it resolve the issue

Comment: Okay.  I really didn't tweak anything.  I refreshed a few times and now it works.  Odd.  But thanks in any event!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("Static-container").on('click', '.add', function() {
        $(this).parent("li").clone(true).appendTo(".doc_list:first");                       
});
```

Where `Static-container` is a selector to the closest elements that holds all the dynamically added `.add` elements.